# Select * group by in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do something that I think is quite simple. Suppose I have a series of records in mongo that have a common key, and variable number of attributes. I want to select all attributes and group by name across the records. For example

```
{ Name: George, x: 5, y: 3 }
{ Name: George, z: 9 }
{ Name: Rob, x: 12, y: 2 }
```

I would like to produce a CSV that looks like this:

```
Name     X   Y   Z
George   5   3   9
Rob      12  2
```

Tried

```
DB.data.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$Name" } })
```

Unfortunately I get back all the names as records but not the union of all the possible attributes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to combine the attributes, you'll need to add those to the `group`.  For example, using [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_addToSet) to find the unique values of the x,y,z attributes grouped by each name:

```
db.data.aggregate(
    { $group : {
            _id : "$Name",
            x: { $addToSet: "$x" },
            y: { $addToSet: "$y" },
            z: { $addToSet: "$z" },
    }}
)
```

Returns:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "Rob",
            "x" : [
                12
            ],
            "y" : [
                2
            ],
            "z" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "George",
            "x" : [
                5
            ],
            "y" : [
                3
            ],
            "z" : [
                9
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a similar thing using $push and it seems to work. My followup question would be whether from here what the best way is to export the data to flat CSV, unwinding the internal arrays in the result set?

Comment: I am using pymongo and python to create the csv. The one remaining issue is that when I use $addToSet I am creating arrays of results for each key, even if there is only one distinct value for each key value pair. This then makes the process of flattening to csv very cumbersome. Is there any way to avoid creating the arrays of key values?

Comment: @RogerSanchez: `$addToSet` or `$push` will return array values, so you will have to do some massaging in your CSV export or consider a different aggregate function.  For example, if all the values are numeric and you only have one unique value per field you may be able to get away with using [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_max) instead.  If the result values are *sometimes* arrays, you will have to wrangle in your code.  Here is an example Python gist that may help: [flattening agg arrays to quoted strings in CSV](https://gist.github.com/a39b087da394b746e4fe).

Comment: Good reference. I ended up solving the flattening issue in a more manual way by creating lists that contain the key names I want, and then using WriteDict to the csv file. Works well. Thanks again for the original mongo grouping answer which was the tricky part.

Comment: I made a mongotry to check the result: http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/index.html#?bookmarkId=52fa5c1a05899e0200d46c2b

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way of doing it :

```
$connection = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
$con        = new Mongo($connection); // mongo connection

$db         = $con->test; /// database
$collection = $db->prb; // table

$keys       = array("Name" => 1,"x"=>1,"y"=>1,"z"=>1);

// set intial values
$initial    = array("count" => 0);

// JavaScript function to perform
$reduce     = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";

$g          = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($g);
```

You will get the answer something like this (**not the exact output**) :

```
Array
(
    [retval] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => George
                    [x] => 
                    [y] =>
                    [z] =>
                    [count] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Rob
                    [x] => 
                    [y] =>
                    [z] =>
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [count] => 5
    [keys] => 3
    [ok] => 1
)
```

Comment: While `group` is a viable option as long as your collection isn't sharded, you shouldn't use PHP examples in non-PHP questions.

Comment: @JohnnyHK : I was searching for it for a long time, i got this link in stack, but it did not give me proper answer, so when i found the answer i posted it here, some one may find it useful, If you really want me to delete i can do that.

Comment: Up to you, but `aggregate` is a better solution in this case and examples should be in JavaScript if possible as that's the 'native' mongo language.  No worries, just letting you know.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: The original question was on the Aggregation Framework rather than `group()` ;-). Your example also isn't complete to get the results grouped by name & counts of attributes (x,y,z). You have currently only grouped by name which is equivalent to the original problem description.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Stennie requires you to know exactly which attributes you want to return from each matching item in the collection you're querying. This isn't always the case.

We had to solve this problem within a Groovy on Grails application we're writing.

We wrote a method like this to handle the "find by X" requests:

```
private List<DBObject> findDistinctPages(Map by) {
    def command =
        new GroupCommand(
                (DBCollection) db.pages,
                new BasicDBObject(['url': 1]),
                new BasicDBObject(by),
                new BasicDBObject([:]),
                'function ( current, result ) { for(i in current) { result[i] = current[i] } }',
                ''
        )
    db.pages.group(command).sort { it.title }
}
```

And then call it within our code as follows:

```
def pages = findDistinctPages([$or: [[type: 'channel'], [type: 'main']]])
```

This works by passing the results of the initial query to the javascript function at the end of the GroupCommand. Mongo only returns the attributes you specify in the initial query and nothing else, so you then have to iterate over the results a 2nd time, populating them with the rest of the data from mongo.

Answer (score -1):

use `$addToSet` to the group,it will work

```
db.data.aggregate(
    { $group : {
            _id : "$Name",
            x: { $addToSet: "$x" },
            y: { $addToSet: "$y" },
            z: { $addToSet: "$z" },
    }}
)
```