# grouping data in mongo using json data stored

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is the data I have in my mongo db:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("556d1c7716efd4a035d8e473"),
    "products": [
        {
            "gtin": 77770000222313,
            "gpc": 10000068
        },
        {
            "gtin": 77770000222312,
            "gpc": 10000068
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I aggregate this so that I get gpc value and then an array under that of the gtins? Something like:

```
{
    "gpc":10000068,
    "gtin":[77770000222312,77770000222313]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select \* group by in mongo aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208771/select-group-by-in-mongo-aggregation)

Comment: @yogesh Please refrain from just flagging duplicates without carefully analysing the OP's requirements first. The question in the duplicate does not involve embedded subdocuments and the answer uses `$addToSet` which won't apply here as that adds only unique elements.

Comment: @chridam I think this kind of question posted many times , If OP's search some more details it will get answers easily instead of posting here, If the OP is really hard to find out solution then we will help here right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation framework

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
      { $unwind: "$products" },
      { $group: { _id: "$products.gpc", gtin: { $push: "$products.gtin" }}},
      { $project: { gpc: "$_id", gtin: 1, _id: 0 }}
    ]
)
```